# Why is isdigit() not working?

Tags: c++, function

**Code:**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string s1,s2,s3,s4,s5;
int ex(string s){
    int i;
    if(isdigit(s)){
        i = atoi(s.c_str);
    }
    else 
        return -1;
    return i;
}

int main(){
    int t;cin>>t;int v1,v2,v3;
    while(t--){
        cin>>s1>>s2>>s3>>s4>>s5;
        v1=ex(s1);
        v2=ex(s2);
        v3=ex(s3);
        if(v1<0) v1=v3-v2;
        if(v2<0) v2=v3-v1;
        if(v3<0) v3=v1+v2;
        cout<<v1<<" + "<<v2<<" = "<<v3;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Error:**

```
error: no matching function for call to 'isdigit(std::string&)'
     if(isdigit(s)){
```

I tried searching all the previous posts regarding this but still could not figure out why `isdigit(s)` function is not working.
And the question is there will be input of the form
`47 + machula = 53`, where machula is some word
and output should be `47 + 6 = 53`.

Comment: You forgot to [`#include <cctype>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit). [`std::isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) is found there.... And it takes a `char` (actually `int` for C compatibility) not `std::string`

Comment: Did just right now, still the same error!

Comment: [`isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) works on characters, not strings. Why not just use [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)?

Comment: See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/). The function is digit takes an int as it argument. Which somewhat confusingly means it takes a single char. So you need to loop over your string passing each digit to `isdigit`. It's much easier and more idiomatic for c++ to `std::stringstream` to convert to int `atoi` has many problems.

Comment: so something like for(j=0;j<s.size();j++) {if(isdigit(s[j]) // code}

Comment: stoi looks like a much better choice here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) is meant to check whether a single character is a digit or not, not a string. That's why the call `isdigit(s)` fails to compile.

You could use [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol). However, keep in mind that it will throw an exception if no conversion could be performed by the function.

```
try
{
   i = std::stoi(s);
}
catch ( ... )
{
   // Deal with the exception
}
```

You could also check whether the first character of the string is a digit before attempting to use [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

```
if ( !(s.empty()) && isdigit(s[0]) )
{
   i = std::stoi(s);
}
```

#### NB

From the comment by @RemyLebeau:

> The above check because that does not guarantee that all characters in the string are digits. `std::stoi()` parses the entire string and then reports the index of the first non-digit character, even if that is the null terminator. It also skips leading whitespace, so checking the first character may cause a false result where `std::stoi()` would have normally succeeded.

Comment: "*You could also check whether the first character of the string is a digit before attempting to use `std::stoi()`*" - be careful, because that does not guarantee that all characters in the string are digits. `std::stoi()` parses the entire string and then reports the index of the first non-digit character, even if that is the null terminator. It also skips leading whitespace, so checking the first character may cause a false result where `std::stoi()` would have normally succeeded.